# Pass branch to job using Jenkins Build Per Branch

Tags: git, jenkins, build

I was able to setup the http://entagen.github.io/jenkins-build-per-branch/ plugin. So I have a template job right now and I would like to pull all changes for a feature-branch when the job runs for that feature branch.

Does anyone have an idea to pass the feature-branch on the git clone/pull of Jenkins in the template job? As far as I know the feature-branch name is only available in the automatically created job names.

So I think I should find a way to cut the branch name from the job name to pass it as parameter when the git clone/pull in jenkins occurs defined in the template job. Does anyone have a working setup with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is automatically passed when the jobs are generated :)